# Apache Spark in Scala Stackoverflow with tail recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, apache-spark, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

The following error occurs:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

When I am performing a tail-recursive function using Scala. I was under the impression that tail recursion in Scala can't overflow and that was one of the strengths of Scala.

Method below:

```
  def gdAll(inputRDD : RDD[(Int, Vector, Int, Vector, Double)]) : RDD[(Int, Vector, Int, Vector, Double)] = {

val step = 0.0000055
val h4 = 0.05

val errors = inputRDD.map { case (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating) =>
  (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating, ((rating - userVector.dot(itemVector)) * itemVector) - h4 * userVector)
}.cache

val currentRMSE = sqrt(errors.aggregate(0.0)((accum, rating) => accum + pow(rating._5 - rating._4.dot(rating._2), 2), _ + _) / errors.count)

val totalUserError = errors.aggregate(Vector(0.0, 0.0))((accum, error) => accum + error._6, _+_)

val usersByKey = errors.map { case (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating, error) =>
  (userid, (userVector, itemid, itemVector, rating, error))
}

val updatedUserFactors = usersByKey.map { case ((userid, (userVector, itemid, itemVector, rating, error))) =>

  (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector + (step * totalUserError), rating)
}

val fullyUpdatedUserFactors = updatedUserFactors.map{ case ((itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating)) =>
  (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating, ((rating - userVector.dot(itemVector)) * userVector) - h4 * itemVector)}

val itemsByKey = fullyUpdatedUserFactors.map { case (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating, error) =>
  (itemid, (itemVector, userid, userVector, rating, error))
}

val totalItemError = fullyUpdatedUserFactors.aggregate(Vector(0.0, 0.0))((accum, error) => accum + error._6, _+_)

val updatedItemFactors = itemsByKey.map { case (itemid, (itemVector, userid, userVector, rating, error)) =>

  (itemid, itemVector + (step * totalItemError), userid, userVector, rating) // totalItemError = itemError
}

val newRMSE = sqrt(updatedItemFactors.aggregate(0.0)((accum, rating) => accum + pow(rating._5 - rating._4.dot(rating._2), 2), _ + _) / errors.count)

println("Original RMSE: " + currentRMSE + " New RMSE: " + newRMSE)

val changeInRMSE = (newRMSE - currentRMSE).abs

if (changeInRMSE < 0.0000005) {

  return updatedItemFactors
}

errors.unpersist()

gdAll(updatedItemFactors) // repeat if change is still large

 }
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Add @tailrec annotation to the gdAll method you think should be tail recursive. Compiler will provide an error if it can't make it tail recursive - for example, gdAll may need to be private. Also I suspect the Serialization error is due to  the use of the method, not the stack overflow.

Comment: Using IntelliJ there is a note next to `gdAll` as seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/6vtriHK.png). I would guess that means it is tail recursive. Could you elaborate on what you mean by the user of the method, not the stack overflow? Thanks

Comment: If the invoker of the method is being serialized, it will result in the Task Serialization error, as RDDs can't be serialized.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm running it from the console. It runs for 20 minutes or and then I get the error? Why would the invoker serialise after 20 minutes worth of running?

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace, and how you're invoking the gdAll method?

Comment: I am running it from the console, I first create an object `val obj = new GD()`. I then call `val currentRdd = obj.gdAll(obj.rddOfEverything)` where `rrdOfEverything` is my pre-formatted RDD in the class `GD`. All of this is done from the console.

Comment: What's the question? Just _"any ideas"_?

Comment: Wondering why, if it's tail recursive,  this occurs. However, a quick look at the PDF you linked explains why! Now the problem is implementing a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the subject of a Spark Summit East 2015 talk, [Experience and Lessons Learned for Large-Scale Graph Analysis using GraphX](http://spark-summit.org/east/2015/talk/experience-and-lessons-learned-for-large-scale-graph-analysis-using-graphx).

What happens is that with each iteration the RDD lineage grows. The lineage is serialized recursively, so at some point this causes a `StackOverflowError`.

Possible workarounds are:

- Stop the iteration before this happens.
- Allocate larger stack (`-Xss`).
- Checkpoint the RDD with `RDD.checkpoint`. (The talk includes details about why this is not a simple fix.)
- Just write out the RDD to disk and read it back.

Comment: I've added the workarounds mentioned in the talk, plus the simplest one, which is simply to stop the iteration before this happens :).

Comment: Thank you, Dan - it's massively appreciated. I've already altered my iteration already (making it shorter) however, I imagined this to be not a great fix as it's iterating for a purpose until it finds something. I'll look into the other methods. Thanks again.